# Instagram ?__a=1 API giving HTML login page in response issue

Tags: java, json, api, httprequest, instagram-api

I have been using this instagram api for a very long time in **Javascript**.

```
https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1
```

Now I moved the same code to **JAVA** and making get call using **HTTP REQUEST** which is obviously a **GET** call.

But now, I am getting login page of instagram in my production but JSON data on my local machine.
I am little bit confused why it is happening. If anyone could help will be great for me.
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to know what's different? Well, a lot.

Calling `https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1` in your browser has access to the `LocalStorage`, `SessionStorage` and `Cookies`. In basic Java, you have none of the above.

And since you have to send a session identifier to Instagram, your Java code won't work without duplicating this logic.

However, the URL you're using is actually not a public API. You may consider using the [Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api) instead and start from there.